# E's-y Word-Square Fill-in

Tags: word, no-computers, word-square

Not necessarily easy, but "'E's-y"!

For each [word square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square) below, the `E`s have been filled in for you.  Your task is to complete the rest of the square using only ***five other distinct letters***.  That is, you may pick any five letters of the alphabet (other than `E`), and use each of those letters as many times as you wish.  Each square uses a different set of five letters, although there may be overlap between squares.  (e.g. if square (1) uses `BFKLZ`, square (2) might use `ABKMR`).

The solutions contain only relatively-common English words that should be known to an educated native English speaker.  There are no abbreviations, slang terms, archaic words, foreign words, or anything else unusual.

$$\begin{array}{rcrc}
  \raise{3em}1.
  &\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline E&&&E&\\
    \hline &E&&&E\\
    \hline &&E&E&\\
    \hline E&&E&&\\
    \hline &E&&&\\
    \hline
  \end{array}
  \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
  \raise{3em}2.\quad
  &\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline &&&E&\\
    \hline &&&&E\\
    \hline &&&&E\\
    \hline E&&&E&\\
    \hline &E&E&&\\
    \hline
  \end{array}\\
  \\
  \raise{3em}3.
  &\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline &&&E&\\
    \hline &&&&E\\
    \hline &&&E&\\
    \hline E&&E&&\\
    \hline &E&&&E\\
    \hline
  \end{array}
  \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
  \raise{3em}4.
  &\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline \;\;\;&&&&\\
    \hline &E&&&E\\
    \hline &&&E&\\
    \hline &&E&&\\
    \hline &E&&&E\\
    \hline
  \end{array}\\
\end{array}
$$

While I can't prevent anyone from writing a computer program to solve these, I would encourage people to try it without.  Where's the fun in brute-forcing a solution?
(Feel free to [use a computer](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/pattern_match.php) to help you find word patterns for a single word, just not to solve the whole puzzle.)

Comment: Can the words go (in a non-crossword manner) from right-to-left and down-to-up?

Comment: @CarlLöndahl No, they cannot.

Comment: I'm expecting at least two of the grids uses 'a'

Comment: This website might help people: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#/media/File:English_letter_frequency_(frequency).svg

Comment: Note to all:  I added a clarification of what I intended by the no-computers tag.  Feel free to use a tool like the one I linked above to help with your word choices -- I just didn't want someone writing a program that solved the entire puzzle for them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the answers all came out piecemeal, I figured I'd post them all together in one answer here, to make it easier for people to see the solutions.

> $$\require{color}
> \definecolor{g}{RGB}{0, 180, 0}
> \begin{array}{rcrc}
>   \raise{3em}1.
>   &NRSTV\quad\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
>     \hline E&\color{g}N&\color{g}T&E&\color{g}R\\
>     \hline \color{g}N&E&\color{g}R&\color{g}V&E\\
>     \hline \color{g}T&\color{g}R&E&E&\color{g}S\\
>     \hline E&\color{g}V&E&\color{g}N&\color{g}T\\
>     \hline \color{g}R&E&\color{g}S&\color{g}T&\color{g}S\\
>     \hline
>   \end{array}
>   \quad\quad\quad
>   \raise{3em}2.
>   &ADGSU\quad
>   \begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
>     \hline \color{g}S&\color{g}A&\color{g}G&E&\color{g}S\\
>     \hline \color{g}A&\color{g}D&\color{g}A&\color{g}G&E\\
>     \hline \color{g}G&\color{g}A&\color{g}U&\color{g}G&E\\
>     \hline E&\color{g}G&\color{g}G&E&\color{g}D\\
>     \hline \color{g}S&E&E&\color{g}D&\color{g}S\\
>     \hline
>   \end{array}\\
>   \\
>   \raise{3em}3.
>   &AHNSV\quad\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
>     \hline \color{g}A&\color{g}S&\color{g}H&E&\color{g}S\\
>     \hline \color{g}S&\color{g}H&\color{g}A&\color{g}V&E\\
>     \hline \color{g}H&\color{g}A&\color{g}V&E&\color{g}N\\
>     \hline E&\color{g}V&E&\color{g}N&\color{g}S\\
>     \hline \color{g}S&E&\color{g}N&\color{g}S&E\\
>     \hline
>   \end{array}
>   \quad\quad\quad
>   \raise{3em}4.
>   &ORSTU\quad\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
>     \hline \color{g}T&\color{g}R&\color{g}O&\color{g}U&\color{g}T\\
>     \hline \color{g}R&E&\color{g}U&\color{g}S&E\\
>     \hline \color{g}O&\color{g}U&\color{g}T&E&\color{g}R\\
>     \hline \color{g}U&\color{g}S&E&\color{g}R&\color{g}S\\
>     \hline \color{g}T&E&\color{g}R&\color{g}S&E\\
>     \hline
>   \end{array}\\
> \end{array}
> $$

Answer (score 8):

Solution for #2

[image]

Used the letters on the right (S,D,G,A,U)

And Solution #4 (probably not what you got)

[image]

Used letters T, R, O, U, S

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain - solution 4 added.

Comment: Good work!  No one managed to solve them all, but I'm giving you the checkmark for getting 2 out of 4, and for getting the hardest one.

Comment: Was #4 actually what you got?!  I thought I was going out on a limb with "trout"

Comment: Yes, it was identical.  I thought there might be many solutions, but I'm starting to think that I was wrong.  Perhaps this is the only valid solution.

Answer (score 7):

Solution for #1

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline E&N&T&E&R\\
    \hline N&E&R&V&E\\
    \hline T&R&E&E&S\\
    \hline E&V&E&N&T\\
    \hline R&E&S&T&S\\
    \hline
  \end{array}

Letters used: N, T, R, S, and V

Comment: Exactly what I had.  I suspect the other answers, with fewer `E`s, might allow for some deviation from my chosen 
solutions.  We shall see.

Answer (score 5):

3: snavh

```
ashEs
shavE
havEn
EvEns
sEnsE
```

Comment: Perfect!  Only one left...