# E's-y T's: Word square fill in

Tags: word, no-computers, word-square

<sup>*This is a follow-up to [E's-y Word-Square Fill-in](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/25633), but you don't need to know anything about that puzzle to solve this one.*</sup>

For each word square below, the Es and Ts have been filled in for you. Your task is to complete the rest of the square using ***exactly twelve other distinct letters***. That is, you must pick any twelve letters of the alphabet (other than E and T), and use each of those letters one or more times. Each square uses a different set of twelve letters, although there may be overlap between squares. (e.g. if square (1) uses BFGKLMOPRSUZ, square (2) might use ABDFKMORSUVX).

The solutions contain only relatively-common English words that should be known to an educated native English speaker. There are no abbreviations, archaic words, foreign words, or anything else unusual.

$$\begin{array}{rcrc}
  \raise{3em}1.
  &\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline \quad&\quad&\quad&\quad&\quad\\
    \hline &&E&&\\
    \hline &E&&&\\
    \hline &&&T&\\
    \hline &&&&\\
    \hline
  \end{array}
  \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
  \raise{3em}2.\quad
  &\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline T&&&&\\
    \hline \quad&\quad&\quad&\quad&\quad\\
    \hline &&&&E\\
    \hline &&&&\\
    \hline &&E&&\\
    \hline
  \end{array}\\
  \\
  \raise{3em}3.
  &\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline T&&&&\\
    \hline \quad&\quad&\quad&\quad&\quad\\
    \hline &&&&\\
    \hline &&&&E\\
    \hline &&&E&\\
    \hline
  \end{array}
  \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad
  \raise{3em}4.
  &\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline &&&&T\\
    \hline \quad&\quad&\quad&\quad&\quad\\
    \hline &&&&\\
    \hline &&&&\\
    \hline T&&&&E\\
    \hline
  \end{array}\\
\end{array}
$$

While I can't prevent anyone from writing a computer program to solve these, I would encourage people to try it without.  Where's the fun in brute-forcing a solution?
(Feel free to [use a computer](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/pattern_match.php) to help you find word patterns for a single word, just not to solve the whole puzzle.)

Comment: I wouldn't use a computer anyway, because there are *only* 787 [5-letter words beginning with a T](https://www.bestwordlist.com/d/t/1/5letterwordsbeginningt.htm) :)

Comment: Is it safe to assume that in each square there are ten unique words (i.e. the symmetry is (mostly) restricted to just the T/Es)?

Comment: @Alconja, judging by the puzzle that this is a follow-up to, no.

Comment: @ev3commander - well that would've been a sensible thing to check... I was definitely making it harder than necessary for myself. Thanks.

Comment: just a clarification, are you allowed to add additional Ts and Es?

Comment: @micsthepick No, all the Ts and Es have been provided.  You must use only the 12 letters you select.

Comment: @Alconja No, the usual definition of a word square is that the same words read vertically and horizontally.  That is the case in all of these puzzles.

Comment: Alright, so since these aren't double word squares then there are only 15 changeable letters, 2 of which are T and E, meaning that only one letter can repeat on the top half. Seems challenging, I'll see if I can solve one

Comment: Oof, I thought I found it, but i keep getting stuck at 11 different letters. This is harder than I thought!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

<s>Just one</s> ...Finally all four! (although I feel there could be "better" solutions for (1) & (2))

> 1. (The 12 other letters are: ACDGHILNORSZ)
>
> ```
>  · · · · ·      Z I N C S
>  · · E · ·      I D E A L
>  · E · · ·  ->  N E G R O
>  · · · T ·      C A R T S
>  · · · · ·      S L O S H
> ```
>
> (...although there's probably a solution without "zincs", it's not exactly a common transitive verb, and "negro" is probably considered archaic.)
>
>  2. (The 12 other letters are: CDHLMNOPRSUY):
>
> ```
>  T · · · ·      T H U M P
>  · · · · ·      H O N O R
>  · · · · E  ->  U N C L E
>  · · · · ·      M O L D Y
>  · · E · ·      P R E Y S
> ```
>
> (...I'm guessing U.S spelling is acceptable, since GentlePurpleRain resides in Canada; here in the U.K., where I am, it would be "honour" and "mouldy". Edit: apparently this is mostly true in Canada too.)
>
>  3. (The 12 other letters are: ADGIKLNORSVW):
>
> ```
>  T · · · ·      T O R S O
>  · · · · ·      O W I N G
>  · · · · ·  ->  R I V A L
>  · · · · E      S N A K E
>  · · · E ·      O G L E D
> ```
>
> 4. (The 12 other letters are: ABCGHLMNRSUY):
>
> ```
>  · · · · T      B L A S T
>  · · · · ·      L U N C H
>  · · · · ·  ->  A N G R Y
>  · · · · ·      S C R A M
>  T · · · E      T H Y M E
> ```

Comment: Nice work! Definitely a difficult puzzle.

Comment: i've guessed the t-word right, but couldnt get the others... well done!

Comment: For the record, it’s honour in Canada too. Most of the time I’ve seen mould officially here as well, although mold is more common than other u-less word variants (color and honor, for example, are much less common in Canada than mold).

Comment: @El-Guest, ah, well it seems I need to clutch at any straws I can find!

Comment: I’m not knocking your answer, I think you’ve done a fantastic job!! (We’re just more British than American for most of our spellings haha!)

Comment: These are all exactly what I had for answers (which is good, because they were the *only* solutions -- at least with the dictionary I used).  Sorry if some of the words seemed less than ideal. I looked at ZINCS as a plural, though perhaps that's just as iffy.  And while I wouldn't normally spell HONOUR or MOULDY the way they are in the puzzle, they are common and legitimate spellings nonetheless.